# WordPress sha1/MD5 password

Tags: wordpress, md5, sha1, password-hash

Recently I was given a job: to edit some pages on site, and I've got a login and password to hosting panel.
The site turned to be running on the WordPress 5.3.3, but a login|password for a WP admin panel was lost.
I was easily found how to reset a password for admin by editing the wp_users table, and I put there an MD5 hash for a simple '12345' password and I got logged in successfully.
But then I tried to change a password to something more complicated. And after that the password field in the wp_users tables has been set to something like $P$BRe9eQ22cXNnM7IZjZgRfR/DLQ7Uh.. that I guess is SHA1 hash. It seems to be all fine, but the problem was that I can't log in anymore.
The same was when I tried to reset the password using an email: the password hash was changed, but I can't log in.
I.e. when the WordPress resets a password it stores it as SHA1, but the login is possible only when the password hash is set as an MD5.
Please, if anybody faced such a problem, let me know how you had solved it.
Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still got access to hosting panel and like to change the admin or any user password in WordPress you can use **Emergency Password Reset Script** just get the username from **wp_users** table.

Steps to follow

- Get the script from https://codex.wordpress.org/User:MichaelH/Orphaned_Plugins_needing_Adoption/Emergency
- Upload to the root of the word press
- Now open the file URL in the browser
- Enter admin username & password for the admin and click **Update Options**

Verify the logins and remove the Emergency Password Reset Script file

And there is no need to change the hashing algorithms types

Comment: Thank you, but there is no question how to reset password.
The question is why the resetting password with standard instruments writes a SHA1 password hash while login required an MD5 hash